# Open Source online private SVN

Tags: svn, open-source

I would like to have a

1. private
2. secure
3. open-source

SVN configured for a minor project with a collaborator.

Googling gave me
http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans
http://www.xp-dev.com/pricing
http://www.projectlocker.com/

What are my options?

Comment: What do you mean by "open source" and "private" in this context? Your requirements don't really make sense. Subversion is an open source project itself, but that doesn't seem to have any relevance to your question. If your project is open source, the private bit doesn't make much sense.

Comment: what i want is a open source private repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other similar SVN repository and project hosting companies include:

> - http://www.codepsaces.com
> - http://repositoryhosting.com
> - http://www.codebasehq.com
> - http://sourcerepo.com

Or you could roll your own and host it yourself by setting up your own SVN server and pairing it up with a project management web application such as:

> - http://www.redmine.org
> - http://trac.edgewall.org

which are both free and open source to use and modify.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for alternatives to the sites you listed, you should also check out [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean private write access, but public viewable, then you can do this with svn permissions. set yourself as read/write and anonymous as read only.

Answer (score 0):

I used devguard in the past, it is good quality and allows you to download nightly backups and such (good for peace of mind ;) ).

I now use github both personally and professionally. Their teams setup is wonderful for working together with multiple people. Besides that, I find git more flexible then SVN :)

Answer (score 0):

github is a personal favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Codesion (http://codesion.com/) is what I have used for a couple of years.  Strong SVN support with good admin.  Includes Trac or Bugzilla as well.